# iOS: присвоить ссылку значению массива

Tags: objective-c, ios, map

Есть `view` разделённый на 3 блока:

```
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewWidth, 0, viewWidth, 210)];
[self setApperanceForLabel:label2];
label2.text = @"Local";
[self.scrollView addSubview:label2];
```

В одном из этих блоков открывается Google карта с мною поставленными маркерами, во втором блоке открывается массив:

```
NSArray *stringsArray2 = @[
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance/1000],
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km",betweenDistance3/1000],
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", betweenDistance4/1000]
];
```

Который показывает расстояние до того или иного маркера. Задача такая: что бы при нажатии на строку массива открывался соответствующей этой строке маркер. Т.е. нажали на:

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance is %f km", betweenDistance4/1000]
```

и открылась карта с такими-то координатами, как такое сделать?

Comment: Поищите пример как работать с UITableView, там увидите ответ.

Я так понимаю вы сейчас пытаетесь изобрести таблицу.

Comment: @AlexDenisov да нет, мне не принципиально будет это таблица или нет, просто хотелось бы что бы работало, а примеров такого приложения я не нашёл

Comment: суть в том, что таблица предоставляет все что нужно: список ячеек с контентом, при тапе на ячейку вызывается событие с индексом выбранной ячейки, по этому индексу можно определить какой пин нужно показывать

Comment: @AlexDenisov а таблицу нужно создавать с navigation controller или без разницы?

Comment: Без разницы, как вам будет удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

В MKPointAnnotation (маркер) у вас есть широта и долгота, и вам нужно реализовать метод из MKMapView **setRegion** чтобы пронавигироваться к этой точке (по координатам). Создаёте CLLocationCoordinate, потом MKCoordinateRegion и присваиваете карте регион. Например так:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = 53.9000;
location.longitude = 27.5667;

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 2500, 2500);

[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
```

P.S. Для работы с картами рекомендую пройти бесплатный и очень хороший курс на Code School - [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/exploring-google-maps-for-ios) от Google